# "Exit" command in console freezes computer, feature or fault?

Tags: command-line, console

After changing to a console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>), logging in, and issuing the command "exit",  my computer hangs (fans speed up, no response from keyboard, black screen) when trying to switch back to GUI (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>/<kbd>F2</kbd>).
Is this a feature of the "exit" command, or a fault?

System: 18.04.2 LTS

Comment: "Logout" had similar consequences. Issuing the commands in a terminal window in GUI does not cause anything similar.

Answer (score 1):

Commenting every line in ~/.bash_logout seemed to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is the result of a known bug in  the `clear_console` command. (For more info, see [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/linux.debian.user/2G71U8P8c3Q) or [here](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/issues/492).)  Just comment out the `clear_console` line in `~/.bash_logout` and the problem should go away.